# Find same rows in the list

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a list of telephone numbers in file telephones.txt. There are more over 2000 telephone numbers in that list.

File format: each row contains **one** telephone number.

I need to find all equal (same?) telephone numbers. The output should contain only telephone numbers which have more than 1 record in the list (I hope I wrote it right in english).

Sample of output:
telephoneNumber count

How can I do this ?

.net 2.0

Comment: Is this an assignment? In any case, please tell us what you've tried. But reading in the list into an array, sorting the array, then traversing it counting how many duplicate entries you get and outputting a row when you get a duplicate seems an obvious approach, since there aren't that many entries.  It would be `sort < telephone.txt | uniq --count --repeated` as a UNIX command line :)

Answer (score 1):

I would read the list into memory (2000 numbers is small).  Sort the list and then walk the list and output the telephone and count when when the previous telephone number does not match the current telephone number.